# How can I find more Juypter execute buttons under VS code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter

Does anyone know how to activate these Jupyter execute buttons as described in https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support

As you can see, my Jupyter notebook under VS Code does not have that many buttons (left).

Is it a GUI bug in VS Code?

[image]

Comment: What extensions did you use in VS Code? And how did you create the "Jupyter" file?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer on this extension. The buttons that you see in the Jupyter support page are for our old webview based UI. Currently we are rolling out a new UI based on VS Codes new native notebook UI. If you are using VS Code - Insiders you get this new UI by default. Also we are starting to roll out the new UI to a small number of stable VS Code users. In the upcoming months we hope to fully move over to the new UI, which looks like what you are seeing now.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/notebooks-are-getting-revamped/

Comment: Hi Ian, thanks a lot for your explanation, have a nice day